# Two sets needed

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Can anyone give an example of a union of an infinite number of closed sets that is not closed? And, complementing that, an infinite intersection of open sets that is is not open?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the first, choose any bounded strictly monotone sequence and let the closed sets be the singleton points in the sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than  repeating and remembering the magic classic examples, $\cup_{n\in \mathbb N}(\frac 1n, 1- \frac 1n)= (0,1)$ and $\cap_{n_\mathbb N}(-\frac 1n, \frac 1n) = \{0\}$ try and think about what this means.

A set is closed if it contains its limit points.  So we need a series points that are limit points to closed sets that converge to a point that is not a point of any of the closed sets.  So let $p_n \rightarrow p$ so that $p_n$ is a limit point of $V_n$ a closed set but $p \not \in $ any $V_n$.  So for example $p_n = \pi$ to the $n-$th decimal place and $V_n = [3, p_n] \cup [p_n + 10^{-n}, 4];$ e.g.$V_n = [3,3.14]\cup [3.15,4]$, then $\cup V_n = [3,\pi)\cup(\pi, 4]$.

Likewise a set if open if every point, p, has a radius in which there are points within the radius that are in the set that are different points that $p$.  So we need a series of open sets where these radii converge to 0.  So let's say $U_n = \{r \in \mathbb R| r$ is within $n$ decimal places of an integer$\}$.  $U_0 = \mathbb R$, $U_1 = \cup (n-.1, n+.1)$ etc.  then $\cap U_n = \mathbb Z$. The Cantor set would be another perfect example. (Pun unintended.)

Comment: Thank you! I think that your answer has been the most informative and helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Classic examples:
$$
\bigcup_{n =1}^\infty [-1 + 1/n, 1 - 1/n]= (-1,1)\\
\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty (-1/n,1/n) = \{0\}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $I_n=[1/n,3-1/n]$ and the union is $(0,3)$ not closed.